# my modal component is not being rendered when i click on the dropdown list item in my react application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd, reduce

i have an ongoing react project. in my dashboard i have an orders folder. inside this i have an order-table and some modals. in order table there is a dropdown and when we click on the list items in the dropdown our modal component is rendered. now this is the code for my orders.js file

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { AssignRider } from './assign-rider';
import { OrderStatusChange } from './change-order-status/order-status';
export const Orders = ({
  filters,
  isLoading,
  orders,
}) => (
  <Styled>
    <h2>ORDERS</h2>
    <div className='content-holder'>
      <OrderTable />
      {
        orders && orders.orders.length
          ? (
            <Fragment>
              <OrderDetail
                selectedOrder={ orders.orders.find(({ number }) => number === selectedOrder) }
              />
              <AssignRider />
              <OrderStatusChange />
              
              
              
              {
                isBypassDeliveryGeoFencingModalOpen && <ConfirmModal
                  isLoading={ isLoading }
                  show={ isBypassDeliveryGeoFencingModalOpen }
                  handleClose={ toggleOrderBypassDeliveryGeoFencing }
                  handleConfirm={ () => bypassDeliveryGeoFencingAttempt(({
                    id: orders.orders.find(({ number }) => number === selectedOrder).id,
                  })) }
                  title='BYPASS DELIVERY GEO FENCING'
                />
              }
              
            </Fragment>
          )
          : ''
      }
    </div>
  </Styled>
);

Orders.propTypes = {
  toggleAssignedSwift: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  assignedSwiftAttempt: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

the code for order-table.js is as follows

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import  Image  from '../../../ui/image/iconImage';

import {
  Styled,
  SortIcon,
  List,
  ListItem,
  OrderImageWrap,
} from './styled';
import {
  ORDER_ACTIONS,
  RESOLUTION_FILTERS,
} from '../../../../utils/values';

import { DropdownAction } from './dropdown-action';
import { PopperDropdown } from '../../../ui/popper-dropdown';

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const CategoryComp = ({data} )=> {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
  const {category, statusReason = '', deliveryTime  } = data;
  if (category === 'gift' ) {return <><p>{ statusReason } </p> <p> { deliveryTime }</p></>;}
  return  <p>{ statusReason }</p>;
};
export const OrderTable = ({
  
  toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing,
  toggleForceDeliverModalVisibility,
  toggleStatusChangeModal,
  toggleUnassignedRider,
  toggleByPassReasonModalVisibility,
  toggleAssignedSwift,
}) => {
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchByPassReason();
  }, [fetchByPassReason]);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetchOrders(filters);
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [fetchOrders, filters, isRefresh],
  );
  useEffect(
    () => () => resetOrdersTableFilters(),
    [resetOrdersTableFilters],
  );
  return (
    <Styled>
      <Legend legends={ [{ status: 'Late at delivery' }, { status: 'Late at pickup' }] } />
      {
        tableData.length ?
          <table>
            <tbody>
              {

                tableData.map((item, index) => (
                  <tr
                    className={ selectedOrder === item.number.value ? 'selected' : '' }
                    key={ index }
                    onClick={ () => setSelectedOrder(item.number.value) }
                  >
                    {
                      columns.map(({ columnName, key }) => (
                        <td
                          key={ `${key}-${columnName}-${index}` }
                          className={
                            (key === 'rider' && item[key].orderStatus === ORDER_ACTIONS.ASSIGN_RIDER)
                              ? 'action'
                              : key === 'number' && DELAY_REASON_COLORS[item.status.split(',')[1]]
                          }
                        >
                          {
                            key === 'status' ?
                              <Status
                                className='status'
                                status={ item[key].split(',')[0] }
                              />
                              : key === 'bypass' ?
                                <DropdownAction
                                  options={ item[key] }
                                  toggleByPassReasonModalVisibility={ toggleByPassReasonModalVisibility }
                                  toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing={ toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing }
                                />
                                : key === 'statusReason' ?
                                  <CategoryComp data={ item[key] }  />
                                  : key === 'number' ?
                                    <OrderImageWrap>
                                      <Image
                                        src={ selectVerticalIcons[item[key].category] }
                                        alt=''
                                      />
                                      <div>
                                        { item[key].value }
                                      </div>
                                    </OrderImageWrap>
                                    : key === 'riderDetail' ?
                                      <div className='tooltipWrap  tooltip-ex'>
                                        <span className='riderName'>{ item[key].name ? item[key].name : '' }
                                        </span>
                                        { item[key].name &&
                                      (
                                        <span
                                          className='tooltip-ex-text tooltip-ex-right'
                                        >{ item[key] ? item[key].name : '-' }
                                        </span>)
                                        }
                                      </div>

                                      : key === 'riderUnassign' ?
                                        <i
                                          className={ orders.orders.find(({ number }) =>
                                            number === item.number.value).rider
                                          && isPermissible(loggedInUser.permissions, 'unassign_order')
                                            ? 'icon-user-minus'
                                            : 'icon-user-minus disable'
                                          }
                                          title={ item[key].props.children }
                                          // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
                                          onClick={ orders.orders.find(({ number }) => number === item.number.value).rider
                                          && isPermissible(loggedInUser.permissions, 'unassign_order')
                                            ? item[key].props.onClick
                                            : () => ({})
                                          }
                                        />
                                        : key === 'resolve' ?
                                          <i
                                            className={
                                              item.status.split(',')[1] ===
                                              RESOLUTION_FILTERS.LATE_AT_PICKUP || item.status.split(',')[1] ===
                                              RESOLUTION_FILTERS.LATE_AT_DELIVERY
                                                ? 'icon-check-circle'
                                                : 'icon-check-circle disable'
                                            }
                                            title={ item[key].props.children }
                                            onClick={
                                              item.status.split(',')[1] ===
                                              RESOLUTION_FILTERS.LATE_AT_PICKUP || item.status.split(',')[1] ===
                                              RESOLUTION_FILTERS.LATE_AT_DELIVERY
                                                ? item[key].props.onClick
                                                : () => ({})
                                            }
                                          />
                                          : key === 'rider' ?
                                            <PopperDropdown>
                                              <List>
                                                
                                                { item[key].isAssigned && (
                                                  <ListItem
                                                    onClick={ item[key].isAssigned ? () =>
                                                      toggleAssignRiderModalVisibility() : () => { }
                                                    }
                                                    disable={ item[key].isAssigned ? false : true }
                                                  >
                                                    <i
                                                      className={ item[key].isAssigned
                                                        ? 'icon-assign' : 'icon-assign disable' }
                                                    />
                                                    <span>Assign Rider</span>
                                                  </ListItem>) }
                                               
                                             
                                                <ListItem onClick={ () => {toggleStatusChangeModal();} }>
                                                  <i className='icon-order-status' />
                                                  <span> Order Status</span>
                                                </ListItem>
                                              </List>
                                            </PopperDropdown>
                                            : item[key]
                          }
                        </td>
                      ))
                    }
                  </tr>
                ))
              }
            </tbody>
          </table>
          : !isOrdersLoading && <Text>
            <div
              style={ {
                display: 'flex',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                padding: '40px 0',
                width: '100%',
              } }
            >
              <h3>No orders available</h3>
            </div>
          </Text>
      }
      {
        totalRecord && !isOrdersLoading ?
          <Pagination
            filters={ filters }
            onPageChanged={ selected => setOrdersTableFilters({
              ...filters,
              page: selected + 1,
            }) }
            pageLimit={ pageSize }
            totalRecords={ totalRecord }
          />
          : isOrdersLoading &&
          <Text className='center'>
            Loading...
          </Text>
      }
    </Styled>
  );
};

OrderTable.propTypes = {
  toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  toggleForceDeliverModalVisibility: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  toggleAssignRiderModalVisibility: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  toggleStatusChangeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

in my container i am dispatching adn mapping and actions adn state to props like this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { OrderTable } from './order-table';
import { actions as ordersActions } from '../../../../actions/orders';
import { actions as uiActions } from '../../../../actions/ui';
import {
  selectOrderTableColumns,
  selectPageSize,
  selectVerticalIcons,
} from '../../../../selectors/orders';
import {
  selectOrdersTableFilters,
} from '../../../../selectors/ui/orders';
import {selectUser} from '../../../../selectors/user';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  selectedOrder: selectSelectedOrder(state),
  tableData: selectTableDataFromState(state),
  totalRecord: selectTotalRecords(state),
  orders: selectOrders(state),
  loggedInUser: selectUser(state),
  selectVerticalIcons: selectVerticalIcons(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setOrdersTableFilters: uiActions.ordersUi.setOrdersTableFilters,
  toggleOrdersTableSort: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleOrdersTableSort,
  toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleOrderBypassGeoFencing,
  toggleForceDeliverModalVisibility: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleForceDeliverModalVisibility,
  toggleAssignRiderModalVisibility: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleAssignRiderModalVisibility,

  toggleStatusChangeModal: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleStatusChangeModal,
};

export const OrderTableContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderTable);
```

in the above component i am listing an item order status change and i am dispatching my action that is in turn changing my redux state in reducer.

now in my component i am getting my state and action

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { OrderStatusChange } from './order-status';
import { actions as uiActions } from '../../../../actions/ui';
import { selectOrderStatus } from '../../../../selectors/ui/orders';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isModalOpen: selectOrderStatus(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  toggleStatusChangeModal: uiActions.ordersUi.toggleStatusChangeModal,
};

export const OrderStatusChangeContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrderStatusChange);
```

and using it

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { ModalBox } from './styled';
import { Modal } from '../../../ui/modal';
export const OrderStatusChange = ({isModalOpen, toggleStatusChangeModal}) => {
  console.log('isModalOpen', isModalOpen);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('this is rendering');
  }, []);
  return (
    <ModalBox>
      <Modal
        show={ isModalOpen }
        handleClose={ toggleStatusChangeModal }
      >
          hello
      </Modal>
    </ModalBox>
  );
};

OrderStatusChange.propTypes = {
  isModalOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleStatusChangeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

but the problem is that this component is not being rendered and i am not seeing any console statement in browser. the flow is actually working in a way that when i click the list item it dispatches an action

```
export const toggleStatusChangeModal = () => {
  return {
    type: types.ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE_MODAL_VISIBILITY_TOGGLE,
  };
};
```

this action is changing my state

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isOrderStatusChangeModalOpen: false,
}
 case types.ORDER_STATUS_CHANGE_MODAL_VISIBILITY_TOGGLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        isOrderStatusChangeModalOpen: !state.isOrderStatusChangeModalOpen,
      };
```

and the state is also being changed as i have debugged it. but the problem is that my component is not being rendered. can anyone solve this problem for me .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the `Orders` component you are importing the undecorated `OrderStatusChange` component

```
import { OrderStatusChange } from './change-order-status/order-status';

...

<OrderStatusChange /> // <-- no props are passed
```

No props are passed to it so `isModalOpen` and `toggleStatusChangeModal` are undefined. In fact, these appear to be declared as required props, so I do believe you should be seeing some React PropTypes warnings about missing props.

```js
OrderStatusChange.propTypes = {
  isModalOpen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  toggleStatusChangeModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

I believe the solution is to import and render the decorated, e.g. Redux-connected, `OrderStatusChangeContainer` component. This component is subscribed to Redux and will pass the missing required props.

```
import {
  OrderStatusChangeContainer as OrderStatusChange
} from './change-order-status/order-status-container'; // I'm guessing at the file name ‍♂️

...

<OrderStatusChange /> // <-- has props injected by connect HOC
```

Comment: well thanks a lot man. it solved my problem. stay blessed adn happy